# Reading data from excel , few cell values have double quotes. How to include the double quotes while reading

Tags: java

In excel sheet, I have a column which contains query in this format "sel * from ABC;" . Users will have to give the value like this as spark engine process the query in this format.

In java code how can i read this value as it as without excluding the double quotes.

Currently it is read as

```
"\"select * from ABC;\"" .
```

how can i make it to

```
 "select * from from ABC;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .replaceAll if it is in a String format:

```
String buf = "\"select * from\"" 
buf = buf.replaceAll("\"","");
```

Comment: it actually fixed by replace("\\\\",""). Thanks Alex.